# Match Phone Numbers Regardless of Formatting

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb

I've written a query for Mongo to search for a phone number.  The gotcha is the phone entry is a `String` rather than a `Number`.  At first I thought it was working fine, however now I realize that if the query isn't formatted correctly it will not match.

So I guess my question is what's the easiest way of matching a phone number regardless of formatting?

Worst case scenario I use a $where statement and check equality by removing numbers from both the values and doing a regex match on that.  Just wondering if there is a more optimal way of doing this?

Comment: `/.+/` will match all phone numbers.

Comment: Except for the empty phone number

Comment: Ah but if the phone number is empty, is it really a phone number? If your soul is empty, are you really a person?

Comment: `/\D*\d{3}\D*\d{3}\D*\d{4}\D*/`  Something like that?  Or do you mean yo have a specific phone number, and you're trying to match it in a messy field?

Comment: Essentially I'm wanting a way of taking a logical phone number search query and having it match a non-unified phone field.  Back in the day it was stored however it was entered, now we have a unified format of entering in these phone numbers.  Say for example, if we have someone call in who was in the system two years ago a search should get their results regardless of the format it was stored in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would store the phone numbers normalized (e.g. either stripped of non numeric chars, or formatted in a standard format) in the DB in the first place, since they are not already normalized, doing it on the fly for each search request will be expensive, so if you don't have too many entries already (e.g. if this is still all in development), a script that will normalize all entries in one shot (or in several batches during off peek hours if you have a production system) will be possible.

Then your where clause will just normalize the input, and then the search will be much easier.

Same goes for addresses by the way, you have to normalize the data to perform good search, or you'll have to develop some fuzzy matching algorithm, that is simply going to be slower. (and might take you more time than you think)

Comment: I definitely agree with you that they should be stored as a normalized number.  I would need to write some setters in the schema to ensure that when saving everything non-numeric is stripped from the entry.  So I'm assuming the only performant way is to convert it to a `Number`?

Comment: Either to a number or to a normalized String (e.g. find a good international phone number format, and enforce it on your input both when saving the number and when searching for it)

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I mentioned this on another comment, we currently are storing all our entries in a certain format, previously the functionality stored the phone numbers the way it was entered.